# I've added cache control to htaccess and gtmetrix still shows a zero score

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to improve the page speed reports, and I keep getting a grade F (0) for leverage browser caching even tho I've tried several examples of code in the .htaccess file

here is the current attempt...

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf|woff|otf|ttf|svg|eot)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Mod Expires is running because if I comment it out I get a http 500 error...

I've also tried setting ExpiresActive like this...

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 

# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# Favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>
```

Am I missing something ? Should the gtmetrix report pick these changes up straight away ?

Comment: right... so it looks like the mod_expires.c is not installed. It's a Plesk 11 server, I guess an email to tech support then...

Comment: Perfect. I found apache modules in Plesk and expires was not enabled. I've enabled it, retested, working. Thanks.